# Localhost software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, localhost

What is a good piece of software to be able to have a set of files hosted from a localhost on Windows 7?

Comment: Your use of "localhost" here I think is different than what most people are used to.  How is what you're describing different than if it was a remote vs. local host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in a LAMP port for Windows (preferring Apache over the built-in IIS) check out [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). It bundles everything you typically need on a web server: Apache web server, MySQL database with web admin UI, PHP and Perl languagues, FTP and mail servers.

There is also [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/), but I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 3):

IIS 7 - really easy to use and it comes with a default website already setup. Just drop your files in and right click the site, then click start.

Comment: I see it can be downloaded for free for 180 days.  Is there a free dev version?

Comment: IIS is included in Windows 7. Here is a documentation of how to install it: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc725762(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using apache. [Using apache on windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/windows.html)

You can install it, then install php ect. as you need them...

If you're looking for ASP/ASPX then either use VS internal web server, or IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your looking for a PHP/Apache/MySQL environment, I would recommend [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). It comes with the latest version of PHP, Apache, MySQL, Phpmyadmin and a pretty easy to use admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

easy php is good stuff, my problem with it is that its just toooo slow... but the features are nice, sometimes you'd not mind the slowness because of the features on the Admin Panel that comes with it... But if you're looking for speed... then XAMPP or IIS is the way to go...
if you install them both you gonna need to configure the Apache and give it a port that does not clash with IIS...